# I have some questions about building an AIR app for use with a connected projector

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, video, air

For an app I'm working on, I'd like to have a control panel window and a video output window to use for projecting video with an attached projector. I have built many Flash applications but this will be my first time using AIR so I have some questions.

1. Is it possible to have two seperate windows as part of one AIR application? Can one of the windows (the video output) be in full-screen mode while the other window stays normal?
2. How does AIR do with playing local video? Will there be crashes or choppy playback?
3. Is there a better language option for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. In fact, the Window class is entirely an AIR phenomenon.
2. a) Just fine. b) Not if your data rate isn't really high. Make sure your video is optimized for streaming playback.
3. Unknown, since you give few details beyond window and controller. If all you're doing is streaming video with a video controller, you could try the QuickTime player itself.